# MySQL error: check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to run query but i am not able to get right output and i am getting this error,i tried some stackoverflow eg. but i not able to resolve it.

**--error---**

> Notice: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near 'LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_manufacturer p2m ON (p.product_id =
>   p2m.product_id) WHER' at line 1
>       Error No: 1064
>
> SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id) AS total FROM oc_product p LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd ON (p.product_id =
>   pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id =
>   p2s.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '1' AND p.status = '1' AND
>   p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '0' LEFT JOIN
>   oc_product_to_manufacturer p2m ON (p.product_id = p2m.product_id)
>   WHERE p2m.manufacturer_id = '8'

**the total code which in which the issue is**

```
public function getTotalProducts($data = array()) {
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id) AS total";
    if (!empty($data['filter_category_id'])) {
        if (!empty($data['filter_sub_category'])) {
                            $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category_path cp LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c ON (cp.category_id = p2c.category_id)";
                        } else {
                            $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_category p2c";
                        }

                        if (!empty($data['filter_filter'])) {
                            $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_filter pf ON (p2c.product_id = pf.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (pf.product_id = p.product_id)";
                        } else {
                            $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product p ON (p2c.product_id = p.product_id)";
                        }
                    } else {
                        $sql .= " FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p";
                    }

                    $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) WHERE pd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' AND p.status = '1' AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'";

                    if (!empty($data['filter_category_id'])) {
                        if (!empty($data['filter_sub_category'])) {
                            $sql .= " AND cp.path_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_category_id'] . "'";
                        } else {
                            $sql .= " AND p2c.category_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_category_id'] . "'";
                        }

                        if (!empty($data['filter_filter'])) {
                            $implode = array();

                            $filters = explode(',', $data['filter_filter']);

                            foreach ($filters as $filter_id) {
                                $implode[] = (int)$filter_id;
                            }

                            $sql .= " AND pf.filter_id IN (" . implode(',', $implode) . ")";
                        }
                    }

                    if (!empty($data['filter_name']) || !empty($data['filter_tag'])) {
                        $sql .= " AND (";

                        if (!empty($data['filter_name'])) {
                            $implode = array();

                            $words = explode(' ', trim(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $data['filter_name'])));

                            foreach ($words as $word) {
                                $implode[] = "pd.name LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($word) . "%'";
                            }

                            if ($implode) {
                                $sql .= " " . implode(" AND ", $implode) . "";
                            }

                            if (!empty($data['filter_description'])) {
                                $sql .= " OR pd.description LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape($data['filter_name']) . "%'";
                            }
                        }

                        if (!empty($data['filter_name']) && !empty($data['filter_tag'])) {
                            $sql .= " OR ";
                        }

                        if (!empty($data['filter_tag'])) {
                            $sql .= "pd.tag LIKE '%" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_tag'])) . "%'";
                        }

                        if (!empty($data['filter_name'])) {
                            $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.model) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
                            $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.sku) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
                            $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.upc) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
                            $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.ean) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
                            $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.jan) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
                            $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.isbn) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
                            $sql .= " OR LCASE(p.mpn) = '" . $this->db->escape(utf8_strtolower($data['filter_name'])) . "'";
                        }

                        $sql .= ")";
                    }

                /*  if (!empty($data['filter_manufacturer_id'])) {
                        $sql .= " AND p.manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_manufacturer_id'] . "'";
                    }*/

                /*  if (!empty($data['filter_manufacturer_id'])) {
            $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_manufacturer p2m ON (p2m.product_id = p.product_id) WHERE p2m.manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_manufacturer_id'] . "'";*/

                    if (!empty($data['filter_manufacturer_id'])) {
            $sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_manufacturer p2m ON (p.product_id = p2m.product_id) WHERE p2m.manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_manufacturer_id'] . "'";


            }

                    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

                    return $query->row['total'];
                }
```

**this the main code which making the error**

```
if (!empty($data['filter_manufacturer_id'])) {
$sql .= " LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_to_manufacturer p2m 
       ON (p.product_id = p2m.product_id) 
       WHERE p2m.manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$data['filter_manufacturer_id'] . "'";
}
```

Comment: echo $sql and show what the actual query is pls.

Comment: You can't do a WHERE followed by a LEFT JOIN with another WHERE

Comment: You cann't add join after where clause which is issue.

Comment: this is in opencart, i don't have idea how to echo it from model

Comment: @wurtel, but i am able to see in many places of opencart they used it without getting any error but when i tried to add in the same way i am getting this error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have mixed ON and WHERE near the line that threw the error. Change your query to look like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT p.product_id) AS total 
FROM oc_product p 
    LEFT JOIN oc_product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) 
    LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_store p2s ON (p.product_id = p2s.product_id) 
        AND pd.language_id = '1' AND p.status = '1' 
        AND p.date_available <= NOW() AND p2s.store_id = '0' 
    LEFT JOIN oc_product_to_manufacturer p2m ON (p.product_id = p2m.product_id) 
        AND p2m.manufacturer_id = '8'
```